# getting json data from php server with "&quot;"

Tags: php, objective-c, json

My iphone app getting json data from php server.

2 basic questions, just to be sure :

1-In some of the json data fields, i see `"&quot;"`, is this how json send Quotes,
and I need to clean it in the iphone app ? or there is elegant and clean way to skip this thing ?

2-The data is in UTF-8, I notice that if there is array in array, the UTF-8 is not display in the right way, and it's show codes. Is this a bug in the JSON library ? or there is somthing to check with the server side ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take a closer look at your own code before leaning towards a bug in the JSON Library or PHP's `json_*` functions.

Comment: just to be sure, in the iphone side,                              im using github.com/stig/json-framework.                           do need to to do somthing specific for UTF-8 handling ? or just sending the string to the parser ? what im doing is :              NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.m_dataToParse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; SBJsonParser *_parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init]; NSDictionary *jsonContentDictionary = [_parser objectWithString:content];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal quote anywhere in a JSON string should be `\"`. `"""` would be invalid JSON and a syntax error. Which "server" is producing this JSON text? The iphone, or PHP's json_encode()?

Comment: the php server is creating the json.
the iphone is downloading the data, and parse it.

what about the array in array ? the data there display the text in codes \u454\u\453 like this, and not text. 
is this a bug in the parser ? or somthing in the server ?

Comment: Do some debugging in PHP and see what's being fed into `json_encode()` as well as what's coming out. I've never seen the function produce mangled output, and it definitely does handle nested arrays properly. However, something else could be doing output filtering in PHP and THAT could be mangling things.

Comment: I'm also using the library you used.
I even updated to the last version, just to be sure there problem is not there.

still,  i got \u434\u434 there.

Answer (score 3):

What's probably happening is that the quote is encoded `&quot;`, and then the ampersand is getting encoded `&amp;quot;`.  It's happened to myself a few time when doing a find and replace on my JSON/XML files.  Just go through and change them back to `&quot;`.

If you're fetching them from another API or source where you can't edit their format, just use

```
html_entity_decode($json->data);
```

around anything you're printing to the page.

Answer (score 1):

> is this how json send Quotes

No. `&quot;` is an HTML or XML entity. A quote in JSON would be `"\""`

> I notice that if there is array in array, the UTF-8 is not display in the right way, and it's show codes. Is this a bug in the JSON library ?

It might be a bug in the encoder. It might be a bug in the decoder. It might be a bug in how you are using one of them.

We can't tell without knowing more about what the input and output looks like.

Comment: just to be sure, in the iphone side, using this library :
im using github.com/stig/json-framework

do need to to do somthing specific for UTF-8 handling ?
or just sending the string to the parser ?

what im doing is :
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.m_dataToParse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SBJsonParser *_parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];

NSDictionary *jsonContentDictionary = [_parser objectWithString:content];

Answer (score 0):

`&quot;` is a HTML entity, a way of representing characters that might otherwise be interpreted as HTML code by the browser.

PHP 5.2/5.3 (can't speak for others) shouldn't touch the html entities, so ensure that you're not running `html_entities(...)` on your json_encode string. Highly doubt the bug is in the encoder.